# Implementing proxy in Android

Tags: android, proxy

I would like to implement a proxy in Andorid so that all my applications (made by me) data should be passed through that proxy so that I could control it. Is it possible or are there any existing ones?

Comment: Your only major challenge is going to be keeping the proxy process running.  Presenting it to Android as a background service is likely the best you can do on a non-rooted device.

Comment: The other major challenges include security (as hackers will gleefully exploit your proxy), customer acceptance (forcing them to download some other APK file just for this proxy), uninstalls (what happens if they remove the app that has the proxy?), and force-stops/task killers (as users may not understand the value of this proxy). I strongly encourage you to come up with some other solution, or to not worry about whatever problem you are trying to solve this way.

Comment: There is a free software (GPLv3) android proxy called [andblock](https://code.google.com/p/andblock/). Its source code is on [github](https://github.com/felixb/adBlock).

Comment: Hi Daniele, I have to do exactely the same thing, I have an app written by my company and I have been asked to monitor it with a proxy, I had a look to andblock (at the moment I am working with a 2.3 android device), but apparently it filters only the web traffic, how can I manage to monitor the data coming from my company's app? This app usually sends a lot of stats to a server, which are http calls, and I have to monitor exaclty these calls. They are sent in backgroung.

Comment: I think there may be some APIs from Android to set proxy now?: developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Proxy